# Messagebox If Loop

Tags: c#, loops

I have a simple message box pop up when a variable is achieved.  It spirals into infinity since I have no stopper. Perhaps it's just my inability to figure out where the stopper is to be placed, but it doesn't seem to halt no matter my solution.

```
if (number == 10)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Woot!");
}
```

Comment: You should show us the rest of the code (I suppose this is inside a loop of some kind?)...

Answer (score 1):

Without more code, you can either use a `break` (as it sounds like you are using a loop), or set your number to something other than 10

```
while(switchstatement)
{
    ...logic...
    if(number == 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("woot");
        break;
    }
    ...more logic...
}
```

Or, you can set the switch that kills your loop

```
while(switchstatement)
{
    ...logic...
    if(number == 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("woot");
        switchstatement = false;
    }
    ...more logic...
}
```

That is based off of limited code...so you may have to provide more code if this is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable but i don't see where you set the value so i assume that you never change it in the loop. Hence you are in an infinite loop.

You could use a `for-loop` instead

```
for(int number = 0; number < 10; number++)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Woot!");
}
```

or in a `while`

```
int number = 0;
while(number++ < 10)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Woot!");
}
```

- [C# **Increment** Int](http://www.dotnetperls.com/increment)
- [**++ Operator** (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)